# where clause with multiple condition using and operator

Tags: sql

Below code is giving an error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "SELECT Items.itm_gsm,
>   Items.itm_" to type 'Long' is not valid. "

```
sql_lotitems3 = "SELECT Items.itm_gsm, Items.itm_size, LotItems.lot_itm_qty
    FROM (Items
    INNER JOIN LotItems ON LotItems.itm_code = Items.itm_code)
    INNER JOIN LotMaster ON LotMaster.lot_code = LotItems.lot_code
    WHERE LotMaster.po_number =" & ponum And "LotMaster.lot_number=" & lotnum
```

It works fine when I use only one condition with the WHERE Clause (either ponum or lotnum) without the and operator of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including `And` within SQL statement with using " after `ponum`.

```
sql_lotitems3 = "SELECT Items.itm_gsm, Items.itm_size, LotItems.lot_itm_qty
    FROM (Items
    INNER JOIN LotItems ON LotItems.itm_code = Items.itm_code)
    INNER JOIN LotMaster ON LotMaster.lot_code = LotItems.lot_code
    WHERE LotMaster.po_number =" & ponum & " And LotMaster.lot_number=" & lotnum
```

Comment: Missed the "&" after ponum.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot!